# Caja - how to reload desktop programmatically

Tags: linux-mint, desktop, caja

I can reload the Caja desktop by clicking anywhere on the desktop pressing F5.  Is there any way to do this programmatically?

For example, I have a user script copies some files to the `$HOME/Desktop` directory.  I'd like the script to be able to do an F5 so the user can immediately see these files instead of them having to manually do an F5.

---

I *can* do

```
caja -q && caja -n &
```

This works, but has the side-effect of killing all other caja windows that happen to be open.

Answer (score 0):

**Answering because I stumbled upon the same issue and found a solution**

To stimulate refresh you can:

1. Install `xautomation` by `sudo apt install xautomation` (you will need `xte` feature provided by it)
2. Create a file named `refresh` and add the following in it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

xte "key F5"
```

3. Finally right click `refresh` file, go to `properties` and check all `Execute` options inside `Permissions` tab
   It can now refresh whenever called